# git for-each-ref --format returns nothing when setting up format to display multiple fields

Tags: git, cmd

I'm trying to display all the current branches while applying criteria regarding what fields I want to see using --format.

When I display only 1 field it's working but as soon as I include multiple fields it returns nothing.

For example this works (returns dates):

```
λ git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate)' --sort=committerdate
'Tue Aug 10 15:32:14 2021 +0200'
'Thu Sep 30 09:35:57 2021 +0000'
'Fri Oct 22 09:54:05 2021 +0000'
'Tue Nov 16 09:58:55 2021 +0000'
'Tue Jul 19 12:20:46 2022 +0000'
'Wed Sep 14 09:55:06 2022 +0000'
'Wed Sep 14 09:55:06 2022 +0000'
'Wed Sep 14 09:55:06 2022 +0000'
'Wed Sep 14 09:55:06 2022 +0000'
'Wed Sep 21 06:35:24 2022 +0000'
'Tue Sep 27 05:44:38 2022 +0000'
'Tue Sep 27 07:59:01 2022 +0000'
'Tue Sep 27 07:59:01 2022 +0000'
```

This works as well (returns branch names):

```
λ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' --sort=committerdate
'refs/tags/1.0.0'
'refs/tags/1.0.1'
'refs/tags/1.0.2'
'refs/tags/1.1.0'
'refs/tags/1.2.0'
'refs/heads/develop'
'refs/heads/master'
'refs/remotes/origin/HEAD'
'refs/remotes/origin/master'
'refs/remotes/origin/develop'
'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/RPA0075-1363'
'refs/heads/release/1.3.0'
'refs/remotes/origin/release/1.3.0'
```

But as soon as I want both fields it returns nothing:

```
λ git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %(refname)' --sort=committerdate
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Work for me. Note that `--format` is _not_ filtering, it is simply formatting

Comment: Works for me in bash/linux. What's your shell / OS ?

Comment: @knittl omg sorry, I meant --format ofc. basically the problem is that it returns nothing when trying to display multiple fields in --format

Comment: @LeGEC I'm using Windows.

Comment: does it work in `git-bash` ?

Comment: @LeGEC it does! just wondering why not in Cmder... anyway I guess I will just be using Git Bash, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Windows-related. `'` do not work as string delimiters in cmd.exe, but are part of regular words.

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %(refname)' --sort=committerdate
```

is parsed as:

```
git for-each-ref --format="'%(committerdate)" --sort=committerdate " %(refname)'"
```

since there is no branch with the name  `%(refname)'`, your output will be empty. To fix, switch to a shell with sensible quoting rules (e.g. Git for Windows ships with Git Bash (which obviously runs Bash)) or use double quotes:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(committerdate) %(refname)" --sort=committerdate
```